# possible bug for Google play game service package name?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, package-name

I publish a game using package name "com.Company.MyGame" sign with "MyKey.keystore", then i publish a Google Play Game Service link with "com.company.MyGame" with "MyKey.keystore". Obviously it doesn't link because of case sensitive.

Now i try to create another Google Play Game Service to link with "com.Company.MyGame" with "MyKey.keystore" but it prompt me an error saying "Package name and certificate fingerprint combination already exists"

But this doesn't make sense since "com.Company.MyGame" should be different from "com.company.MyGame"

Is this a bug from google side or did i miss something? also can anyone provide me a solution on this?

sorry for my bad english and i appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, for those who wonder or have same issue.

Turn out i do have a duplicate project which i deleted long ago, but when you go to the page where you can set your project API and click on "manage all project", the deleted project actually still there and you'll have to delete it here.

Comment: Yes, the Google Play services setup can be extremely annoying (and quite buggy). Whenever you work with this, it is good advice to always check all the settings in your Android Developer dashboard AND your Google Developer dashboard. I've seen a fair number of issues caused by inconsistencies in the settings across the different systems.