# package name and certificate fingerprint combination already exists

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting an error while trying to add google play services like below:

> Package name and certificate fingerprint combination already exists

How can I handle this?

Comment: The question would be more answerable with more detail, i.e. what exactly did you try when you got the error.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same, i followed these steps it's working fine now.

1. Click on Remove this app from Enter THE APP DETAILS section.
2. Change the pacakge name of the application that you are trying to
   add.
3. Now replace the newly created package name in ENTER THE APP DETAILS
   section.
4. Now just give the SHA1 finger print key
5. Done.

Comment: If I rename package name, how can I do updates of app? Will it give error, when I add new version if apk on Google Play Console?

Comment: We can't change package name of an existing app, it means we have to publish it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a duplicate project which you deleted long ago, but when you go to the page where you can set your project API and click on "manage all project", the deleted project actually is still there and you'll have to delete it there.

Check these questions:

- [Google play services error with generating OAuth2.0 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605834/google-play-services-error-with-generating-oauth2-0-client)
- [possible bug for Google play game service package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253324/possible-bug-for-google-play-game-service-package-name)